# Retreive the string from the fourth comma

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, etl

i have a dataframe and one of the column contain address and i want to retrieve the city from string. For example i want to retrieve Umbria from below. (the city name is after the 4th comma)

```
Strada statale 71 Umbro Casentinese, Case Lunghe, Città della Pieve, Perugia, Umbria, 06062, Italia'
```

i have tried find below but only return the index

```
a = 'Strada statale 71 Umbro Casentinese, Case Lunghe, Città della Pieve, Perugia, Umbria, 06062, Italia'
a.find(','4)
return : 35
```

Comment: `s.split(',')[4]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if `pandas` (which I assume you're using) has any built-in functionality for this or not. 
If it does,  it's preferable because it will be much faster than any python code you'll write.

But this is how to do it in pure python:

```py
def get_chunk(text, split_str = ",", pos = 4):
    # split the string into chunks (frags) #
    text = text.split(split_str)

    # assuming all your addresses use the same format, this'll get you the City #
    return text[pos]


get_chunk(a) # output: Umbria
```

Or you can just do a simple one-liner instead of a whole function:

```py
city = a.split(',')[4]
```

Comment: Should use `.strip()` to remove leading and trailing space as well.